# fence - codechef april 2019 long challenge

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, c++14

In the following question I am getting only 2 correct answers for the code given below. Please help me with what cases are going wrong.

https://www.codechef.com/problems/FENCE

The idea is to account for every fence encountered when we travel row and column wise.

Once a plant is encountered 2 edges are counted (in both row-wise and column-wise traversal), the previous is checked for adjacency in the row or column. If adjacent, the 2 common edges are subtracted.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

typedef long long int ll;

bool sortbysec(const pair<ll,ll> &a,const pair<ll,ll> &b) 
    { 
    return (a.second < b.second); 
    } 

int main() {

    ll t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        ll n,m,k;
        cin>>n>>m>>k;
        vector<pair<ll,ll>> a(k,make_pair(0,0));
        ll count=4;
        if(k==0) count=0;
        else{
            ll x,y;
            int l=1;
            cin>>x>>y;
            a[0]=make_pair(x,y);

            for(ll i=1;i<k;i++){
            ll x,y;
            cin>>x>>y;
            a[l]=make_pair(x,y);
            if(a[l]!=a[l-1]) l++;
            }

            sort(a.begin(),a.end());

            for(ll i=1;i<k;i++){

            if((a[i-1].first==a[i].first && a[i-1].second+1==a[i].second)) count-=2;
            count+=2;
            }

            sort(a.begin(),a.end(),sortbysec);

            for(ll i=1;i<k;i++){

            if((a[i-1].second==a[i].second && a[i-1].first+1==a[i].first)) count-=2;
            count+=2;
            }
        }
        cout<<count<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What have you done to narrow it down? What is the data set that is failing? What is the expected result for that data set?

Comment: Also, what method do you use to solve the problem ? It can be helpful for external readers to have a summary of your code rather than to have to read and understand it.

Comment: What do you use `sort` for ? It seems strange to see a call to a sorting function to solve this problem.

Comment: `if(k==0) count=0;` is already wrong: the problem statement says that it is impossible to leave the field without crossing the fence.

Comment: (OT: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h))

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write an algorithm where you construct the grid, this has at least complexity of O(MN) and as you can see in the constraints NM <= 10^18 which is not feasible.

You have to write an algorithm with complexity O(K), because we know the number of plants  K <= 10^5.

It can be done pretty easily:

1. Create a `HashMap<Integer, HashSet<Integer>>` where you put in all the plant values. The goal is to query adjacent cells in O(1).
2. Then for each plant you add `4 - adjacent plants` to the fence sum. E.g. if you want to test if `{3, 7000}` has a plant to the left, you do `map.containsKey(2) && map.get(2).contains(7000)`. Like this you don't even need special treatment of plants at the border of the grid.